# Tomcat primary secondary setup in multiple AWS EC2 instances

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, high-availability

I have got a java application war file deployed inside a tomcat (primary) server of an AWS EC2 instance.
This war typically performs some backend tasks and does NOT directly interact with any end users.
I have created a similar tomcat (secondary) server inside another EC2 instance and deployed the same war file.

How can I set up the primary & secondary tomcat instances such that the secondary EC2's tomcat can become active automatically incase if the primary EC2's tomcat goes down?

Answer (score 0):

The issue not on Tomcat. You bring up multiple, and either they all act on their own or can even share session information when running as a [cluster](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html). This cluster targets an active/active setup.

However unless your application is aware of that and supports that use case, your only option is to run one Tomcat including your war at a time. So you are searching for an active/passive setup and may need additional software as listed in [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster).